# I'm finding it hard to insert into 3 tables at the same time in C# MySql [ERROR] 'Parameter '@lastBatch' must be defined. Please Suggest?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, windows, workbench

This `INSERT INTO` query is working in MySql workbench, but not in c#.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO product_batch(batchNumber) VALUES(@batchNumber); SET @lastBatch = last_insert_id();  INSERT INTO company(nameCompany) VALUES(@nameCompany); SET @lastCompany = last_insert_id();  INSERT INTO product(name, purchase_price, sale_price, idBatch,idCompany) VALUES(@name, @purchase_price, @sale_price, lastBatch, lastCompany)";
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBoxItemName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_price", textBoxCostPrice.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_price", textBoxSalePrice.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchNumber", textBoxBatchNum.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameCompany", textBoxCompany.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully ");
    connection.Close();
    dataGridDisplay();
    addNewProductFunction();
    functionReadOnlyTrue();
}
```

[This is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2CR1.png)

Comment: Do **not** post images of error messages. Paste the **text**.

Comment: **This is the Error** : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Fatal error encountered during command execution.'  _Inner Exception_ .. MySqlException: Parameter '@lastBatch' must be defined.

Comment: You can and should [edit] the question to add such vital information.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `Allow User Variables = true` in the connection string.
Secondly the problem was with the **datatype** in the MySql database.

otherwise my code was working perfectly. now the **problem has been resolved!**

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in SQL statements with MySQL, you must set the `Allow User Variables=true` connection string option: https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#AllowUserVariables

If you were using [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), you would have gotten a helpful exception message that would have provided the solution.